# Photoelectric Effect

Tags: photons, photoelectric-effect

My textbook goes on explaining variations of photo current/stopping potential and frequency/intensity of the light used. 
My doubt is what effect does the amplitude of light wave have on photo current and stopping potential?

Comment: Amplitude is equivalent to intensity, changing amplitude will bring the same results as changing intensity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intensity of a wave is directly proportional to the square of the amplitude of the wave. Mathematically speaking, $I \propto a^2$. So, increasing the amplitude increases the intensity of the wave. And the increase in intensity of the incident radiation increases the number of photo-electrons, but it does not affect the stopping potential of the concerned metal surface.

Comment: But my teacher told us that intensity is related to number of photons per second. Is that also correct?

Comment: Yes, it can be taken as an analogy at max. That is, you are relating the wave property of light (intensity) with its particle property (no. of photons). This is possible since *light has dual nature*. But in general, one should take this thing strictly or rigorously.

Comment: Yes amplitude of light is the number of photons.  Light is made up of individual photons.